# Catch PHP flush echo in ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, flush

I am working on process that upload pictures to Facebook .Because i want to upload more then one picture in request, i want to get update on the status of the uploaded pictures by flush the picture object that return from Facebook api. I am using flush() and ob_flush().
my code :

```
public static function response($data, $status = 200) {
    if (!headers_sent()) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 " . $status . " " . self::getRequestStatus($status));
    header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
    }

    echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
```

I run the request on browser (google chrome). and  it work fine, i get the first content as

```
{"data":[{"id":"123456...}]}
```

And after few seconds i get the next content. now I am triyng to send the request vie ajax request to the server. the request:

```
        var sendRequest = function (path, method, parameters, handler) {
            $.ajax({
                url: path,
                data: parameters,
                type: method,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.data)
                        data = data.data;

                    handler(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    ErrorsManager.showError(xhr.responseText == '' ? '' : JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).error);
                    handler(null);
                }
            });
        };
```

If i send one picture its work fine.
but if i send 2 pictures its return `unexpected error <`
and the flush is not working (i can see that by using phpStorm debug)
My feeling that it something with the headers. i tried to change the header to `application/octet-stream` but it didn't help.